# How to show global validation message with Bootstrap Validator by 1000Hz

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap validation by 1000Hz ([see here](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#))
Is possible to show global message after submiting form? For instance

```
There are some error in your form.
```

Or do I have to manage it by myself?

Comment: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-usage end of the page, no?

Comment: No no, it's just a validation message for one field. I need the global warning message ("There are some errors in your form.") when trying to submit form and some errors occured.

Comment: I don't see how the sample at the end of the page does not apply, but I'm no expert.